# Insert space with babel post-hyphenation

Tags: babel, hyphenation

In czech, we write date ranges with en-dash without spaces, e.g.

> 1351–1362

It is not allowed to break the line around the dash. Instead, when necessary, it should be typeset as

> 1351 až 1362

where "až" means "to" or "until". Then the linebreak can occur after the word "až".

Ranges like these occur a lot in the book I'm working on. Therefore, I wish to use babel extended hyphenation rules to sort this issue out automatically.

I created a `\babelposthyphenation` rule for a character `§` that would be used instead of the endash in these cases. It works as expected except, **I can't figure out how to insert a space in front of the word "až".**  I couldn't find the answer at [the babel wiki](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/non-standard-hyphenation-with-luatex.html) and I don't understand the source code well enough.

Here is the result (MWE that compiles with `lualatex` and the latest version of babel below). The first line shows the desired result.

[image]

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[papersize={85mm, 100mm},showframe]{geometry}

\babelposthyphenation{czech}{.§.}{
    {},
    { no = --, pre = až, post = , data = 1 },
    {}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent profesorem 1351--1362 a~v~roce 1353~až 1372

\vspace*{2ex}
\noindent profesorem 1351§1362 a~v~roce 1353§1372
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the moment `\babelposthyphenation` deals with words only, so glues and kerns cannot be inserted. There will be a `\babelprehyphenation` which will allow more general transformations, but anyway I don't think this is the best way and the @egregs 's way is much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put skips in the prebreak, postbreak and nobreak texts. You can have a kern, though. It won't participate on space stretching or shrinking in the line.

Two methods, I'd prefer the first because it carries more semantic.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[papersize={85mm, 100mm},showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\breakrange}{\discretionary{\kern0.3333em až}{}{--}}
\newcommand{\yrrange}[2]{#1\breakrange#2}
\newunicodechar{§}{\breakrange}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent profesorem \yrrange{1351}{1362} a~v~roce \yrrange{1353}{1372}

\vspace*{2ex}
\noindent profesorem 1351§1362 a~v~roce 1353§1372

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would "`{} pre = až`" work, or does that count as a skip?

Comment: @egreg This works great, exactly what I was after, thanks a lot! I also like the first method better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton if I understood you correctly this does not work. I get ```Inserting `Babel.hyphenate' at position 1 in `hyphenate'.[\directlua]:1: '}' exp
ected near 'pre'.
\babelposthyphenation ...ce = { \babeltempb } }) }
                                                  \endgroup```

Comment: @Ondrian -- I'm not really familiar with the innards of babel, so the suggestion was a wild guess,  Thank you for confirming that it doesn't work.  This might save someone else from wasting time.  I don't know whether this situation is addressed in the babel documentation , but if it isn't, it might be a nice addition.